# Reshape long panel data to wide where data is not unique within ID

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
| State | Year | Industry | Employment |
|-------|------|----------|------------|
| AL    | 2014 | 1        | 123345     |
| AL    | 2015 | 1        | 145411     |
| AL    | 2016 | 1        | 149402     |
| AL    | 2014 | 2        | 153518     |
| AL    | 2015 | 2        | 157773     |
| AL    | 2016 | 2        | 163156     |
| AK    | 2014 | 1        | 167187     |
| AK    | 2015 | 1        | 167863     |
| AK    | 2016 | 1        | 163320     |
| AK    | 2014 | 2        | 162419     |
| AK    | 2015 | 2        | 166116     |
| AK    | 2016 | 2        | 170136     |
```

I would like to end up with a dataset that looks as follows:

```
| State | Year | Employment_Industry1 | Employment_Industry2 |
|-------|------|----------------------|----------------------|
| AL    | 2014 | 123345               | 153518               |
| AL    | 2015 | 145411               | 157773               |
| AL    | 2016 | 149402               | 163156               |
| AK    | 2014 | 167187               | 162419               |
| AK    | 2015 | 167863               | 166116               |
| AK    | 2016 | 163320               | 170136               |
```

As you can see, the data I have is in long format but the years are repeated within a `State` by `Industry`. This is causing an issue when I `reshape wide`.

I generated IDs for a couple of different variable groupings, but I end up with an error to the effect of:

> values of variable Industry not unique within ID

What kind of an ID do I need to create, or is there something I can do to create the desired dataset?

Comment: Although @Pearly Spencer gave a fine answer, what's missing from the question is precisely what `reshape` code you tried and indeed quite how you produced `ID` as as a new variable. In a programming forum giving the code you used really is key. The nub of the matter is that `State` and `Year` are joint identifiers, so `reshape` must be told that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear
input str2 State Year Industry Employment
AL 2014 1 123345    
AL 2015 1 145411     
AL 2016 1 149402     
AL 2014 2 153518     
AL 2015 2 157773     
AL 2016 2 163156     
AK 2014 1 167187     
AK 2015 1 167863     
AK 2016 1 163320     
AK 2014 2 162419     
AK 2015 2 166116     
AK 2016 2 170136   
end  

egen id = group(State)
reshape wide Employment, i(id Year) j(Industry)

drop id
order State Year Employment*

list, abbreviate(15) sepby(State)

     +------------------------------------------+
     | State   Year   Employment1   Employment2 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. |    AK   2014        167187        162419 |
  2. |    AK   2015        167863        166116 |
  3. |    AK   2016        163320        170136 |
     |------------------------------------------|
  4. |    AL   2014        123345        153518 |
  5. |    AL   2015        145411        157773 |
  6. |    AL   2016        149402        163156 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```